# Equality of custom object in NSMutableSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, equality, nsmutableset

I'm having some difficulties adding custom equality checks to one of my own objects.

I have a custom `Message` object which has a unique `messageID` property which is an `NSString`, as well as other information about the message.

The objects are being stored in an `NSMutableSet`, so uniqueness is required in the collection, but I need them to be unique based on the `messageID`, not the default.

I have added the following code in order to do so.

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    if (![object isKindOfClass:Message.self]) {
        return false;
    }

    if (object == self) {
        return true;
    }

    Message *otherMessage = (Message *)object;

    if ([otherMessage.messageID isEqualToString:self.messageID]) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    return [self.messageID hash];
}
```

However when I start adding instances of `Message` objects to a set, the app (sometimes, not always) crashes on one of the following lines:

```
if ([otherMessage.messageID isEqualToString:self.messageID]) {
```

OR

```
return [self.messageID hash];
```

Basically whenever it tries to access the `messageID` property.

And the error I get is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is `messageID` declared? How is it set? Show some more relevant code.

Comment: Nesting both points of crash within respondsToSelector: is likely to prevent the crash but may have side-effects. Can you verify this?

Comment: If only I'd remembered to change `assign` to `strong` when I updated the `messageID` property from an `NSInteger` to `NSString`! Thanks rmaddy for the comment that made me realise how stupid the issue was!